# Sceneview Camera Node full screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, artoolkit

I'm trying to set the size of the `camera node` to be the same as the `scene view`. I've managed to set the `scene view` to fit the full screen, this is been proven by setting the background colour of this. This was achieved by the code below:

```
CGRect aFrame = self.sceneView.frame;
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

aFrame.size.width =  screenWidth;
aFrame.size.height = screenHeight;

self.sceneView.frame = aFrame;
```

However when I initialise my camera node it doesn't seem to fill the scene view and I don't know how to access and set its size so the camera fills the whole screen. I'm fairly new to objective-c so all help is appreciated.

The code for the camera node can be found below:

```
 - (nonnull SCNScene *)createScene {
  SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene scene];
  SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
  cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
  cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 10);
  [scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];
  _cameraNode = cameraNode;

  _trackableNodes = [NSMutableArray new];
  return scene;
}
```

Comment: So, do you have a specific node in the screen you would like to fully fill the SCNView?

Comment: @drewster I managed to fix it by setting the preset, however, I've not got another problem where the segue isn't happening instantly assuming because of the update loop it is stuck in.

Comment: sounds like that's probably an unrelated issue.  You should post your solution here for others, and post your new issue to a new question, if needed